# Change shell from ksh to bash and change prompt in .profile

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm using this in my .profile to switch to bash on login:

```
case $- in
  *i*)
    # Interactive session. Try switching to bash.
    if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then # do nothing if running under bash already
      bash=$(command -v bash)
      if [ -x "$bash" ]; then
        export SHELL="$bash"
        exec "$bash -l"
      fi
    fi
esac
```

Is there a way to get the following to execute automatically after the bash shell opens?

```
PS1='\[\e[1;91m\][\u@\h \w]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

I put the line in a .bash_profile but it does not change the prompt.

Comment: have you tried to run "chsh" to change your login shell?

Comment: not installed, this is on a very old solaris box

Comment: i wonder how old your bash is.. what if you have to export the PS1 variable? do you have truss installed? maybe use truss to see if it reads in .bash_profile.. or add debug echo statements to bash_profile to see if it is being executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For interactive shell, put the `PS1` line in your `~/.bashrc`, not in `~/.profile` and source it :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

(or loggoff/in)

Moreover, if you'd like to permanently change your shell :

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

or edit as root with `vipw` or `editor /etc/passwd`

Comment: it worked with .bashrc vs .bash_profile

Comment: Invoking `chsh -s /bin/bash [username]` may throw the error `chsh: can only change local entries; use ypchsh instead.`.

Answer (score 2):

This should just work:

```
...
export SHELL="$bash"
PS1='\[\e[1;91m\][\u@\h \w]\$\[\e[0m\] ' exec $bash -l
...
```

If you have root or similar privilege:

```
usermod -s $bash dave111
```